# Ubuntu 20.04 no sound on desktop dual boot along side Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, sound

I am new at Ubuntu. Recently I decide to use Linux. So I install Ubuntu 20.04 along side windows 10. I install Ubuntu by following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-Hv9hOaKso). After opening Ubuntu I realize I do not find any sound. I tried many ways but I can not fix it.

This is the pulse Audio volume Control screenshots Playback:
[image]
output devices
[image]
[configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jkbg.png):

This is my `lspci` output. lspci Output:
[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you install PulseAudio Volume Control and post a screenshot of it? https://linuxhint.com/pulse_audio_sounds_ubuntu/

Comment: I just edited my post. is this the right thing you want?

Comment: My sound problem is fixed but my microphone is not working still now

Comment: Can you type" lspci " and post a screenshot of it. It will tell you if ubuntu detects your audio device correctly and which version its using.

Comment: @MugdhoMNS I add the output of "lspci" on this post.